# Import a script from package in setup.py

Tags: python-3.x, configuration, python-import, setup.py

I want to use a `setup.py` which imports from a script which is part of the package that has to be installed. This script just contains a `dict` that contains the strings for creating entry points. I haven't hardcoded them in the `setup.py` because I want to use this list again later from the installed package.

Just for clearance here my directory structure and important files:

```
PackageA
|_package_a
| |_models
| |_modules
| | |_do_query.py
| | |_...
| |_setup_cfg.py
| |_ __init__.py
| |_...
|_ __init__.py
|_setup.py
```

**`__init__.py`** in **`package_a`:**

```
from .setup_cfg import setup_config
```

**`setup_cfg.py`:**

```
setup_config = {
    'scripts': [
        'do_query'
    ]
}
```

**`setup.py`:**

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from .package_a import setup_config

with open('README.rst') as f:
    readme = f.read()

with open('LICENSE') as f:
    license = f.read()

setup(
    ...,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['{}=package_a.modules.{}:main'.format(script, script) for script in setup_config.get('scripts')]
    },
)
```

I can make the import `from .package_a import setup_config` and pycharm resolves this import correctly. However, if I try to install the package via `pip3 install .` it fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.package_a'; '__main__' is not a package`

(we use `pip` instead of `python setup.py install` as we want to have the whole source folder installed in site-packages instead of a bundled version)

Can anyone explain me that exception or provide a proper way to achieve such a configuration? (The dict in `setup_config.py` must be accesible from `setup.py` as well when importing the installed package.

Comment: you are trying to import everything `*` from directory. you can use such import method in file only. i.e. you can use `from .package_a.modules._do_query import *`

Comment: Sorry, already corrected this one but posted it wrong. I corrected it. Same exception anyway.

Comment: Five and a half years late, here's the official guide on slurping in a package resource in `setup.py`, focuses on the version number but the techniques should work equally well for a dict: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar problem, and also resolved it in very strange way, i really don't know the reason it is working, even i thought it should not work.

i just imported without relative path

eg:

```
from package_a import setup_config
```

just removed the relative path(**dot removed**), it worked. pycharm is throwing error, but when in ran `pip3 install .` it worked. please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This technique is really useful if you want to keep a version string in exactly one file within your package, and reuse that version string in your setup.py file.  For example I have an open API spec file that starts:

```
openapi: 3.0.3

info:
  version: 0.5.8
  title: Super Data Service
  ...
```

The module version.py parses and publishes the version string:

```
import importlib_resources

__version__ = "0.0.0"
yaml_path = importlib_resources.files('mypackage').joinpath('openapi.yml')
with importlib_resources.as_file(yaml_path) as yaml:
    with open(yaml, "r") as fileh:
        for line in fileh:
            line = line.strip()
            if line.startswith('version:'):
                __version__ = line.split()[1]
                break
```

And finally here's how I used that in setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from mypackage import version


setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version=version.__version__,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests.*", "tests"]),
    ...
```

HTH